# Theory of Variable Neutral Filter

Tags: filters, variable-nd

I know what an ND filter does. I know what a polarizer does. I also know what two polarizers stacked together and rotated properly do. I also know that two polarizers are not the best solution. 
My question is, how variable ND filters works in theory. What is difference theoretically between good variable ND filter and two polarizers properly stacked together and rotated.
Thank you

Comment: As far as I know variable ND filters are all implemented using two polarizers so there's no difference (except that you can't separate the two filters to use as regular polarizers).

Comment: The first sentences of this question are copied verbatim from the question I marked as duplicate. Something is fishy here.

Comment: yeah, that's weird...

Comment: I voted NOT to close since 2 polarizers stacked is not exactly mechanically the same as a special purpose variable ND filter (which is made of 2 polarizers stacked). Admittedly, the whole point of the question escapes me, but it is interesting.

Comment: @PaulCezanne -- but that's what the other question asks...

Comment: it does, it does! (Excuse, hard month at work...)

Comment: changed my vote also...

Comment: ND filters and Variable ND filters are two totally different animals. Since every VND filter I've ever seen or heard of is, in fact, two stacked polarizers they have as much if not more in common with polarizing filters as they do with conventional ND filters. They have a LOT more in common with two stacked polarizers than they do with a conventional ND filter!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How does a variable ND filter work?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/63940/11924) (or, the other is a dupe of this...)

Answer (score 2):

Matt Grum is right but I can think of one difference.

Variable Polarizers have a well known problem with very wide angle lens. You get strange banding in your image since the light travels so obliquely through the filters.

Two polarizers could have a greater gap between them which could exacerbate this effect.

Comment: Is the banding from the gap or from the light from wider field changing incoming angle across the frame in a more pronounced way? (as seen in threads like this: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/31540057 )